# Can several publishers publish on a single topic

Tags: ros, publisher, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

... or that doesn't make any sense?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12059/can-several-publishers-publish-on-a-single-topic/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible and sometimes even useful. For example: we are using it to teleop our robot from multiple devices (by keyboard and android smartphones) that all publish to the /cmd_vel topic.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5